# Extension of a linear map in a generic vector space (without Zorn's lemma)

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, linear-transformations, axiom-of-choice, hahn-banach-theorem

I am studying topological vector spaces from Sevres' book "Topological vector spaces, distributions and Kernels".
In one of the preparatory chapters I encountered the following excercise:

Consider a linear subspace M of a vector space E, and a linear map T from M into F. 
Prove the existence of an extension T': E into F.
(Obviously all the spaces may be infinite dimensional)

I have studied a bit of functional analysis so I think that maybe one could  mimic the proof of Hahn-Banach theorem and in this context one should neither take care of the continuity of the extension. However I recall that this proof uses explicitly Zorn Lemma, or the Axiom of Choice.
Being a bachelor's student, I was wondering if in this more simple context this could be avoided. I was trying to exploit quotient spaces or to find a decomposition by means of direct sum E= M + M' but was not successful.
Any idea ?

Comment: As far as I remember, the axiom of choice in the proof of Hahn-Banach theorem was used to extend our functional to the whole of the vector space. It had nothing to do with continuity. Zorn's lemma is something that is more of an algebraic nature rather than analytic. Even the statement that every vector space has a basis is proved using Zorn's lemma. Plus, I'm an undergrad student too and Zorn's lemma and it's equivalent formulations were probably the basis of our first course in math which was about naive set theory.

Comment: @FrancescoBilotta Because a Banach space is a special case of a topological vector space and because some (weak) form of AC is needed for the Banach spaces via Hahn-Banach, I do believe that you should help yourself with AC when finding a proof.

Comment: Plus, since you're looking for a proof that avoids the axiom of choice, your question is really a question in logic. I would remove the linear algebra and linear-transformations tag and add two tags related to logic instead.

Comment: @stressedout you're not being very polite overall, and moreover you could simply answer that AC is needed. What is more, I am pretty aware that AC is used to extend the functional, but I was wondering if a more direct approach could be exploited. Normally I don't wake up every morning and use Axiom of Choice

Comment: @FrancescoBilotta Are you serious? What part of what I said sounded impolite to you? lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the case $F=M$ and $T$ the identity map on $M$.
An extension of this to $T': E \to M$ is a projection of $E$ on $M$.  Then with $N = \ker(T')$ you can write $E = M \oplus N$.

According to Asaf Karagila's answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/163923/properties-of-vector-spaces-without-ac), the Axiom of Choice is equivalent to the statement that this can always be done.

Comment: I think I also wrote better references in answers on this site...